# JIRA plugin velocity properties

Tags: java, encoding, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

How can I change the encoding for JIRA plugin velocity template properties?

I've changed properties file from:

```
<jira-install>/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/velocity.properties
```

adding output and input encoding = UTF-8 didn't help.

(cyrillic) I know about i18n.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change with Velocity, and why? If installed correctly, I believe that JIRA already uses UTF-8 for everything.

Comment: @ScottDudley just simple html template with tabs and title of this tabs in cyrillic. I know i could use i18n files to title and other thing, but i want to know for experiment "can i change it?". I tried added velocity properties in another not jira project and it worked, without properties didn't. Here is the link to screenshot [oi60.tinypic.com/i4jlnq.jpg]

Comment: I understand now. It looks like it's broken and the templates will always be treated as ISO-8859-1 regardless of what you do. They're not going to fix it: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-37132 I don't know why editing the velocity.properties manually didn't work, but you're probably going to have to put your UTF8 characters in a separate .properties file and use $i18n.getText("other.java.property") instead. You could also try writing your code as [Soy templates](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Using+Soy+Templates) instead of Velocity, which may not have the same problem.